# managing/building multiple ios app instances (flavours)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, gradle, ios8

**Is there any tool similar to gradle (android) for building ios apps?**

I have the same code base and multiple (10+) app instances (flavours) which differs in resources such as images, localization, configs, product names, versions... I'd like to manage my instances in similar way I did it with gradle on android, as described here [multiple instances of android app - git project management best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541655/multiple-instances-of-android-app-git-project-management-best-approach/28966344#28966344).

I found one project [gradle-xcodePlugin](https://github.com/openbakery/gradle-xcodePlugin) but I'm not aware if it is even capable of managing resources like I'm used to from android, couldn't find it in docu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved building app flavours with this approach, I created:

1. appropriate **targets** in xcode, each per app flavour,
2. resources folders (**res**), each per app flavour, separate to the project folder, with this structure:

   [image] 
   **common_imgs** are images common for all flavours. **img** folder images specific for an app flavour. **Info.plist** is config file for target's Info tab. **config.plist** and **colors.plist** are my specific configs for each app flavour.
3. **Launch Screen File** for each app flavour attached to the specific target
4. **App Icons Source** for each app flavour attached to the specific target
5. **Launch Images Source** for each app flavour attached to the specific target
6. **script** for switching resources, which simply overrides res folder witch appropriate resources for particular app flavour
7. **helper scripts** for creating colors, configs and Infos from android resource xmls

The worst and most pain is always to create Launch Screen File and Launch Images - running different simulators and saving screenshots, then drag&dropping to appropriate target. For App Icons I use http://makeappicon.com/# and again d&d madness. For everything else, I have the helper scripts .

Comment: Would you please share a sample project?

Comment: @uzairshahzad sorry, I don't have access there anymore, it's a long time ago.